# Private key authentication has been deprecated from the CLI. Please refer to the following documentation for more details

Tags: amazon-web-services, soap, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use AWS api tool to obtain spot price history.

But when I use `'ec2-describe-spot-price-history'`, it shows:

> Private key authentication has been deprecated from the CLI. Please refer to the following documentation for more details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-soap-api.html

Here is my configuration in .bash_profile

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
alias ll="ls -l"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
export CLASSPAHT=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export EC2_HOME=/Users/XXX/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ec2-api-tools-1.7.5.1
export AWS_ACESS_KEY=pk-XXXXXXXXXX.pem
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=cert-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
```

Comment: @D.M: please don't get into the habit of adding backticks (inline code formatting) to everything. AWS is a proper noun (and an acryonym) so that should be all caps with no code formatting. Inline formatting is OK for errors, but arguably quote blocks are better - if you make such an edit, format the whole error please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for the correction..will keep in mind next time...

Answer (score 1):

From the [link you mentioned](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-soap-api.html):

> If you are using the Amazon EC2 CLI tools, you can no longer use the `EC2_PRIVATE_KEY` and `EC2_CERT` environment variables. You must use the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` variables instead.

It seems that you just changed the environment variable names, but `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` don't take certificates, but [access key pairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) instead. So generate a pair of access keys, properly set the environment variables and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you! I used  X.509 Certificates as access key pairs. After I change it, it works well. Thanks so much.